# NO WRAP Challenge in Material UI List, ListItemText

Tags: css, material-ui

Is there a way to no wrap text in `ListItemText`?

[image]

I need ListItemText just to cut words without any expansion or scrolls.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us a sample ?

Answer (score 9):

As of Material UI version 5.0.6 You can override the `ListItemText` using the `primaryTypography` prop.

More info on the [ListItemText Api Documentation](https://mui.com/api/list-item-text/)

> **primaryTypographyProps:** These props will be forwarded to the primary typography component (as long as disableTypography is not true).

This would mean that the props passed will be passed to a [Typography Component](https://mui.com/api/typography/)

To hide or wrap the text we can restrict the width of the ListItem (if needed depending on parent) in this case setting the `maxWidth` to 300px, and then use the `primaryTypographyProps` and pass a `style` object that will have the `whiteSpace`, `overflow` and `textOverflow` set to hide.

```
import { ListItem, ListItemText } from '@mui/material';

<ListItem
    sx={{
        maxWidth: 300
    }}
>
    <ListItemText
        primary={"Super long string that needs to be wrapped"}
        secondary={"other text not important"}
        primaryTypographyProps={{ 
            variant: 'subtitle2', 
            style: {
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
            }
        }
        secondaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'caption' }}
    />
</ListItem>
```

For more control you can also disable Typography and pass your own component that has its own styling entirely if you prefer.

> **disableTypography**: If true, the children won't be wrapped by a Typography component. This can be useful to render an alternative Typography variant by wrapping the children (or primary) text, and optional secondary text with the Typography component.